# Correct prepositions for "named"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

What're the common prepositions which can be used after "named"?

For example:

The rocky island named {by, for, from, after} its large pelican  colony.

In this sentence which preposition is correct and why?

Answer (score 2):

In this case the correct preposition is *for* as the pelican colony can be considered to be a distinguishing or noticeable feature as in:

> Pelican Island, the rocky island *named for* its large pelican colony.

Named *after* is appropriate when the name comes from a proper noun, such as a person's name.

> Pelican Island, the rocky island *named after* its discoverer, Sir Francis Pelican.

Named *by* indicates who gave it the name.

> Pelican Island, *named by* the first settlers in the area.

Named *from* is used when the name comes from something else, such as a member of a group where the specific member is not named.

> Pelican Island, like other islands in the group, was *named from* the various bird species found in the area.

Comment: Oh! (+1) I like that you researched further.

Comment: Thank you very much @mick